# How to remove a field from sequelizejs findOne object?

Tags: sequelize.js

For an object returned from sequelize 6.x `findOne()`, how to delete a field named `fielda`?

tried `delete obj.fielda` and it didn't work. Can not use `excludes` in query as `fielda` is needed for other case.

Comment: assigning empty string with obj.setDataValue(fielda, "") works.

Comment: Just get the plain object by calling method `get()` of returned model instance and you can modify it any way you want